# GCP SDK API for Policy Analyzer for Python

Tags: python-3.x, api, google-cloud-platform

I can see the Service Account usage out of gcloud CLI by doing as such:

```
gcloud policy-intelligence query-activity --activity-type=serviceAccountKeyLastAuthentication --project=<project_name>
```

I would like to replicate this in a python script..

I am attempting to this do this but I am not sure how to authenticate, and I am getting a 401 error, despite having enabled the API. I am following this documentation. https://cloud.google.com/policy-intelligence/docs/activity-analyzer-service-account-authentication#iam-get-service-account-key-id-rest

```
import requests
 r = requests.get(f"https://policyanalyzer.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{self.project_id}/locations/global/activityTypes/serviceAccountKeyLastAuthentication/activities:query?filter=activities.full_resource_name%3D%22%2F%2Fiam.googleapis.com%2Fprojects%2F{self.project_id}%2FserviceAccounts%2F{self.sa_email}%2Fkeys%2F{self.key_id}%22"
```

Is there some way I need to authenticate my request call? The rest of the script I am using the python client libraries using discovery.build and authenticating as such:

```
credentials, project = google.auth.default()
self.crm = discovery.build("cloudresourcemanager", "v3", credentials=credentials)
```

There does not seem to be a "policy analyzer" python library, so I am not sure on next steps.

The end goal is to see the last key authentication time of every service account key in the organization.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may check this link for the sample [Python code](https://github.com/googleapis/python-asset/pull/132#issuecomment-741991718)

Do note that the feature is still in preview and does not have a Python client for the same yet. The gcloud cli and REST is the way of accessing this feature programmatically.

Comment: ah I see.. thanks, the thread is from 2021 so I suppose the python client isn't coming.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the python example shown towards the bottom of the page here:
https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts.keys/list

It shows how to get application default credentials used to pass in the client. You could accomplish the same with http requests, but that example above should help.

Also, looking at the original curl request, if you decode the filter to unicode it *should* be:

> activities.full_resource_name="//iam.googleapis.com/projects/PROJECT_ID/serviceAccounts/SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL/keys/KEY_ID"

Assuming you got it from the sample [curl][1] request.
[1]: https://cloud.google.com/policy-intelligence/docs/activity-analyzer-service-account-authentication#view-recent-specific-key